# Fetching multiple urls with aiohttp in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Since Python 3.5 introduced `async with` the syntax recommended in the [docs](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) for [`aiohttp`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aiohttp) has changed. Now to get a single url they suggest:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        html = loop.run_until_complete(
            fetch(session, 'http://python.org'))
        print(html)
```

How can I modify this to fetch a collection of urls instead of just one url?

In the old `asyncio` examples you would set up a list of tasks such as

```
    tasks = [
            fetch(session, 'http://cnn.com'),
            fetch(session, 'http://google.com'),
            fetch(session, 'http://twitter.com')
            ]
```

I tried to combine a list like this with the approach above but failed.

Comment: Could you explain what is your fail?

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov Wonderful to hear from you. What I mean is I could not understand how to do it. When I define a list of tasks then use `results = loop.run_until_complete(tasks)` I get a runtime error. `async with` is such a new feature with so little literature that it would be super convenient for people learning to use it if the `aiohttp` doc showed an example of grabbing more than one url. The library looks terrific, just needing a bit of hand-holding to get started. Thank you!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For parallel execution you need an [asyncio.Task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task)

I've converted your example to concurrent data fetching from several sources:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        if response.status != 200:
            response.raise_for_status()
        return await response.text()

async def fetch_all(session, urls):
    tasks = []
    for url in urls:
        task = asyncio.create_task(fetch(session, url))
        tasks.append(task)
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results

async def main():    
    urls = ['http://cnn.com',
            'http://google.com',
            'http://twitter.com']
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        htmls = await fetch_all(session, urls)
        print(htmls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks a million! Accepting your answer, but... 1. there's still a typo with the placement of the parenthesis. I'll edit it if you don't mind. 2. It looks to me like to print the actual result the line `print(html)` is deceiving and you actually need something like `print('\n'.join(list((str(some_task._result) for some_tuple in html for some_task in some_tuple))))`, maybe that could be added to the answer? 3. This seems really useful, I'd recommend adding something like this to readthedocs. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Andrew, where can I put a test like `if response.status == 200`? If one url does not exist, the script breaks, and I am not understanding where to check the response within the `async with session.get(url) as response: return await response.text()`

Comment: Thank you to the other person who left a comment before. I have started a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926917/fetching-multiple-urls-with-aiohttp-handling-errors) to clarify this.

Comment: Updated to aiohttp 3.x and python 3.7 usage

Comment: Where is loop defined?

Comment: @Kalimantan `main()` is just ordinary coroutine. Create a task from it and run in event loop as you would do with any other coroutine.

Comment: Hey, does this preserve the order of the urls? i.e. is `htmls[i]` the response to `urls[i]`?

Comment: the `asyncio.create_task` part is not necessary. Task is created from the coroutine in 3.7.

Comment: When I ran %timeit for this example and compared it to requests, requests was slightly faster (?) Is this approach optimal?

Comment: Instead of an `if` conditional for the status, simply do `session.get(url, raise_for_status=True)`