# asyncio web scraping 101: fetching multiple urls with aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-asyncio, aiohttp

In earlier question, one of authors of `aiohttp` kindly suggested way to [fetch multiple urls with aiohttp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35879769/) using the new `async with` syntax from `Python 3.5`:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()

async def fetch_all(session, urls, loop):
    results = await asyncio.wait([loop.create_task(fetch(session, url))
                                  for url in urls])
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # breaks because of the first url
    urls = ['http://SDFKHSKHGKLHSKLJHGSDFKSJH.com',
            'http://google.com',
            'http://twitter.com']
    with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        the_results = loop.run_until_complete(
            fetch_all(session, urls, loop))
        # do something with the the_results
```

However when one of the `session.get(url)` requests breaks (as above because of `http://SDFKHSKHGKLHSKLJHGSDFKSJH.com`) the error is not handled and the whole thing breaks.

I looked for ways to insert tests about the result of `session.get(url)`, for instance looking for places for a `try ... except ...`, or for a `if response.status != 200:` but I am just not understanding how to work with `async with`, `await` and the various objects.

Since `async with` is still very new there are not many examples. It would be very helpful to many people if an `asyncio` wizard could show how to do this. After all one of the first things most people will want to test with `asyncio` is getting multiple resources concurrently.

**Goal**

The goal is that we can inspect `the_results` and quickly see either:

- this url failed (and why: status code, maybe exception name),  or
- this url worked, and here is a useful response object

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I would use [`gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) instead of `wait`, which can return exceptions as objects, without raising them. Then you can check each result, if it is instance of some exception.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()

async def fetch_all(session, urls, loop):
    results = await asyncio.gather(
        *[fetch(session, url) for url in urls],
        return_exceptions=True  # default is false, that would raise
    )

    # for testing purposes only
    # gather returns results in the order of coros
    for idx, url in enumerate(urls):
        print('{}: {}'.format(url, 'ERR' if isinstance(results[idx], Exception) else 'OK'))
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # breaks because of the first url
    urls = [
        'http://SDFKHSKHGKLHSKLJHGSDFKSJH.com',
        'http://google.com',
        'http://twitter.com']
    with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        the_results = loop.run_until_complete(
            fetch_all(session, urls, loop))
```

Tests:

```
$python test.py 
http://SDFKHSKHGKLHSKLJHGSDFKSJH.com: ERR
http://google.com: OK
http://twitter.com: OK
```

Comment: Terrific, thank you so much! I'll need to digest this, but after playing around with it a bit it seems to be quite flexible. +1, accept. :)

Comment: Great answer. One thing I am curious about, since you immediately iterate over the results after doing `asyncio.gather` wouldn't it be better to do `asyncio.as_completed` on the list of `fetch`es? This way you can iterate over the completed ones immediately versus waiting for them all to finish?

Comment: @dalanmiller: it requires exceptions handling, like in Padraic Cunningham answer. But if you need result for each Future immediately then this is the way.

Answer (score 9):

I am far from an asyncio expert but you want to catch the  error you need to catch a socket error:

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(10):
        try:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                print(response.status == 200)
                return await response.text()
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e.strerror)
```

Running the code and printing *the_results*:

```
Cannot connect to host sdfkhskhgklhskljhgsdfksjh.com:80 ssl:False [Can not connect to sdfkhskhgklhskljhgsdfksjh.com:80 [Name or service not known]]
True
True
({<Task finished coro=<fetch() done, defined at <ipython-input-7-535a26aaaefe>:5> result='<!DOCTYPE ht...y>\n</html>\n'>, <Task finished coro=<fetch() done, defined at <ipython-input-7-535a26aaaefe>:5> result=None>, <Task finished coro=<fetch() done, defined at <ipython-input-7-535a26aaaefe>:5> result='<!doctype ht.../body></html>'>}, set())
```

You can see we get catch the error  and the further calls are still successful returning the  html.

We should probably really be catching an *OSError* as socket.error is   [A deprecated alias of OSError](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html#socket.error) since python 3.3:

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(10):
        try:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                return await response.text()
        except OSError as e:
            print(e)
```

If you want to also check the response is 200, put your if in the try too and you can use the reason attribute to get more info:

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(10):
        try:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                if response.status != 200:
                    print(response.reason)
                return await response.text()
        except OSError as e:
            print(e.strerror)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Two great answers, I wish I could select both. Picking @kwarunek 's because it works out of the box, but +1 and I'll go find two of your best answers to upvote. :)