# From a list of URLs search each page and return results with matching page type

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have one domain that I would like to do an extensive search on with all URLs equal except for the ending, which I have compiled in a list.

The goal is to search each of these pages and identify the pages that return a 'Page not found' error, and return them to the console - my search would be for this:

```
<h1 class="center error-page-center" id="error-message">Oops! We couldn’t find what you wanted.</h1>
```

I have been trying to do this using BeutifulSoup, so far to no avail

```
import psycopg2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page in pages:
    page = connection.cursor.execute("select concat('https:mywebsite/',integervalue) as url from table")
    search = soup.find_all(class_="center error-page-center"):
        if len(search)>0: 
        print ("Needs removal")
```

Considering that there are several thousand pages I want to search, are there other approaches that would be more efficient?

My code will result in error, I am more interested in looking for any advice on how to search a list of URLs for that specific body of text.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for url in urls:
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        # Do something when request fails
        print e.code
    else:
        print(url) # succesfful url
                   # write your code.
```

[Python tool to check broken links on a big urls list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52984173/python-tool-to-check-broken-links-on-a-big-urls-list)