# Fetching multiple urls with aiohttp in python

Tags: python-3.x, api, web-scraping, python-asyncio, aiohttp

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879769/fetching-multiple-urls-with-aiohttp-in-python-3-5), a user suggested the following approach for fetching multiple urls (API calls) with `aiohttp`:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


url_list = ['https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment/?q=Nestle&size=30&after=1530396000&before=1530436000', 'https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment/?q=Nestle&size=30&after=1530436000&before=1530476000']

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.json()['data']


async def fetch_all(session, urls, loop):
    results = await asyncio.gather(*[loop.create_task(fetch(session, url)) for url in urls], return_exceptions= True)
    return results

if __name__=='__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    urls = url_list
    with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        htmls = loop.run_until_complete(fetch_all(session, urls, loop))
    print(htmls)
```

However, this results in only returning Attribute errors:

```
[AttributeError('__aexit__',), AttributeError('__aexit__',)]
```

(which I enabled, otherwhise it would just break). I really hope there is somebody here, who can help with this, it is still kind of hard to find resources for `asyncio` etc. The returned data is in json format. In the end I would like to put all json dicts in a list.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Working example:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import ssl

url_list = ['https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment/?q=Nestle&size=30&after=1530396000&before=1530436000',
            'https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment/?q=Nestle&size=30&after=1530436000&before=1530476000']


async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url, ssl=ssl.SSLContext()) as response:
        return await response.json()


async def fetch_all(urls, loop):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        results = await asyncio.gather(*[fetch(session, url) for url in urls], return_exceptions=True)
        return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    urls = url_list
    htmls = loop.run_until_complete(fetch_all(urls, loop))
    print(htmls)
```

Comment: ```async with aiohhtp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False))``` no more tears to cry

Comment: @Jannik looks strange, which version of aiohttp\python you are using?

Comment: @YuriiKramarenko i am using aiohttp==0.7.2, asyncio 3.4.3 and python 3.6

Comment: @YuriiKramarenko you were so right. I updated it, now it works! thank you so much. I have no idea, why my version was so outdated

Comment: Not working for me got below error : RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

Comment: @Krissh the problem is here `loop.run_until_complete(fetch_all(urls, loop))`, your loop has been already ran. Just call `await fetch_all(urls, loop)`

Comment: asyncio.get_event_loop is deprecated in Python 3.10. https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It is bit dated, but finding this saved me a ton of time and adjusting to modern version is nearly trivial.