# Converting from requests to aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I currently have this class for making requests to an API and caching the JSON response:

```
import os
import pathlib
import json
import hashlib
import time

import requests


class NoJSONResponseError(Exception):
    pass


class JSONRequestCacher(object):
    """Manage a JSON object through the cache.

    Download the associated resource from the provided URL
    when need be and retrieve the JSON from a cached file
    if possible.
    """
    def __init__(self, duration=86400, cachedir=None):
        self.duration = duration
        self.cachedir = self._get_cachedir(cachedir)
        self._validate_cache()

    def _get_cachedir(self, cachedir):
        if cachedir is None:
            cachedir = os.environ.get(
                'CUSTOM_CACHEDIR',
                pathlib.Path(pathlib.Path.home(), '.custom_cache/')
            )
        return cachedir

    def _validate_cache(self):
        """Create the cache directory if it doesn't exist"""
        self.cachedir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    def _request(self, url):
        """Perform the retrieval of the requested JSON data"""
        return requests.get(url)

    def save(self, raw, cachefile):
        """Save the provided raw JSON data into the cached file"""
        with open(cachefile, 'w') as out:
            json.dump(raw, out)

    def load(self, cachefile):
        """Retrieve the saved JSON data from the cached file"""
        with open(cachefile) as cached:
            return json.load(cached)

    def cache_is_valid(self, cachefile):
        """Check if cache exists and is more recent than the cutoff"""
        if cachefile.is_file():
            cache_age = time.time() - cachefile.stat().st_mtime
            return cache_age < self.duration
        return False

    def request(self, url, refresh=False):
        """The JSON data associated to the given URL.

        Either read from the cache or fetch from the web.
        """
        urlhash = hashlib.md5(url.encode()).hexdigest()
        cachefile = self.cachedir.joinpath(urlhash)
        start = time.time()
        if not refresh and self.cache_is_valid(cachefile):
            return self.load(cachefile), True, time.time() - start
        resp = self._request(url)
        resp.raise_for_status()
        try:
            raw = resp.json()
        except ValueError:
            raise NoJSONResponseError()
        self.save(raw, cachefile)
        return raw, False, resp.elapsed.total_seconds()
```

I then have other classes and code which call the `request` method of this code like so:

```
class APIHelper():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = JSONRequestCacher()

    def fetch(val):
        url = 'my/url/{}'.format(val)
        return self.cache.request(url)

    def fetchall(vals):
        repsonses = []
        for val in vals:
            responses.append(self.fetch(val))
        return responses
```

For a small number of `vals` this is fine and it's really no big deal to wait 10 mins. However I am now looking at making 30,000+ hits to this endpoint. In the past I have used threadpools (`multiprocessing.dummy.Pool`) to achieve some parallelism, however from my reading it seems like `async/await` and `aiothttp` is a better way to go. Unfortunately try as I might I cannot wrap my head around how to translate that to this code. I am using Python 3.8.

**EDIT**
I tried making this change:

```
class JSONRequestCacher():
    def __init__():
        self.http = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    async def _request(self, url):
            async with self.http.get(url) as response:
                return await response.read()
```

Got the error: `AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'json'` from my `raw = resp.json()` line

Tried then adding `resp = await self._request(url)` but that is `SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function`. Then if I make `request` an async function then calling it just seems to return me a coroutine object that doesn't give me the expected response.

And this is just trying to make the `_request` call async. I can't even start to understand how I am meant to make multiple calls to it via another class (`APIHelper`).

Comment: What have you tried and what specific problem are you having?

Comment: I looked at some fetch/fetch all examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51726007/6529697) and I tried to apply async/await to my call to `_request` but I kept getting various errors where it seemed i was returning a coroutine. So I tried using `async with` at the `raw=resp.json()` but that’s errored because it wasn’t in an async function apparently

Comment: What errors? Show us the code and the errors you got.

Comment: Edited with what little I could manage. Part of the problem is I fundamentally am struggling to wrap my head around using async/await in classes like this, as all the examples I've found are for simpler functions, often where the URLs are hardcoded, and typically where the thing calling `fetchall` is the same one making the underlying request

Comment: Using async/await in classes is no problem at all, you just define a class method as `async def bla(self, ...)` and it works totally fine, you can await it and everything. The problem you're more likely to have is that you need to convert your **whole program** to asyncio if you want to use aiohttp (or anything else async). Your `main` needs to be async (typically executed with `async.run(main())`), and you need to await async functions all the way down. For example, you cannot just randomly have a `request` function that is _not_ async, and invoke async stuff from it.

Comment: So if I want to be using concurrency (or something approximating it at least) for just my `fetchall` and I don't want people using my `APIHelper` class to have to concern themselves with how it's run then I need to go back to just using a threadpool?