# python - how to submit concurrent api requests for trading purposes

Tags: python, python-multithreading, pytest-aiohttp

So I have a list of instruments in a csv that looks like this:

```
EUR_HUF
EUR_DKK
USD_MXN
GBP_USD
CAD_CHF
EUR_GBP
GBP_CHF 
...
```

To submit an order on an individual instrument is done by doing this api request:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import logging
import json

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer 83da58ee4d8b630115ba04368ed6916c-db53699ac5f596bfd495b835571ed878"
}

async def post(session,instrument):
    headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer 83da58ee4d8b630115ba04368ed6916c-db53699ac5f596bfd495b835571ed878"
    },

    data = {
        "order": {
            "units": 1,
            "instrument": instrument,
            "timeInForce": "FOK",
            "type": "MARKET",
            "positionFill": "DEFAULT"
        }
    }
    async with session.post(f"https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/101-004-22347481-001/orders") as response:
        return await response.text()


async def pre_post(instruments):
    data = {
        "order": {
            "units": 1,
            "instrument": instruments,
            "timeInForce": "FOK",
            "type": "MARKET",
            "positionFill": "DEFAULT"
        }
    }
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        results = await asyncio.gather(*[post(session,instrument) for instrument in instruments])
        return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    instruments = [ "EUR_HUF",
        # "EUR_DKK",
        # "USD_MXN",
        # "GBP_USD",
        # "CAD_CHF",
        # "EUR_GBP",
        # "GBP_CHF"
        ]
    response = loop.run_until_complete(pre_post(instruments))
    print(response)
```

Now I want to submit an order concurrently for all instruments in my instrument csv. I have looked into threading and AIOhttp but I am not sure how to apply it to my scenario.

Any guidance or example would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below you'll see an example of how you can send the requests concurrently.
Do note that this code isn't complete.
`acc_num` and `token` are missing since they weren't specified in your question. This should give you an idea and won't require much to modify for your needs.

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def post(session, token, acc_num, instrument):
    headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
    }
    data = {
        "order": {
            "units": 1,
            "instrument": instrument,
            "timeInForce": "FOK",
            "type": "MARKET",
            "positionFill": "DEFAULT"
        }
    }
    async with session.post(f"https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/{acc_num}/orders") as response:
        return await response.text()


async def pre_post(instruments):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        results = await asyncio.gather(*[fetch(session, token, acc_num, instrument) for instrument in instruments])
        return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    instruments = [ "EUR_HUF",
        "EUR_DKK",
        "USD_MXN",
        "GBP_USD",
        "CAD_CHF",
        "EUR_GBP",
        "GBP_CHF" 
        ]
    response = loop.run_until_complete(pre_post(instruments))
    print(response)
```

Borrowed some code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51728016/18777481.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I changed the fetch to post but It doesnt work. it looks as though its performing each request without the headers

Comment: I copied the headers to be outside the first function which seems to fix it. But now I am unable to include the data params for each request.

Comment: Hi, did you try adding the `headers=headers` and `data=data` params to the post?

Comment: I updated the original question with the code I am trying now. It seems it doesnt take the data=data into account

Comment: @Harry You need to pass the data argument to the POST request, `async with session.post("...", data=data)`

Comment: Thank you for your help dude! It works YOURE A LEGEND!!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to KevinssaDev, I manage to fix it. Here is the complete solution

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import logging
import json

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer 83da58ee4d8b630115ba04368ed6916c-db53699ac5f596bfd495b835571ed878"
}

async def post(session,instrument):
    headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer 83da58ee4d8b630115ba04368ed6916c-db53699ac5f596bfd495b835571ed878"
    },

    data = {
        "order": {
            "units": 1,
            "instrument": instrument,
            "timeInForce": "FOK",
            "type": "MARKET",
            "positionFill": "DEFAULT"
        }
    }
    async with session.post(f"https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/101-004-22347481-001/orders",data=json.dumps(data)) as response:
        return await response.text()


async def pre_post(instruments):
    data = {
        "order": {
            "units": 1,
            "instrument": instruments,
            "timeInForce": "FOK",
            "type": "MARKET",
            "positionFill": "DEFAULT"
        }
    }
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        results = await asyncio.gather(*[post(session,instrument) for instrument in instruments])
        return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    instruments = [ "EUR_HUF",
        "EUR_DKK",
        "USD_MXN",
        "GBP_USD",
        "CAD_CHF",
        "EUR_GBP",
        "GBP_CHF"
        ]
    response = loop.run_until_complete(pre_post(instruments))
    print(response)
```